# Jquery - hide on click anywhere on document

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a div that hides whenever you click outside of it but I'm having some trouble getting certain links inside the div to work (and not hide the div).

```
$(document).click(function() {
    fav.hide();
});
theDiv.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

That is what I have for the whole clicking outside and closing event. Heres the thing: I have two types of links in my div, one regular link and another which is a javascript one. The regular one redirects OK but the javascript one doesn't do anything.

Could somebody help me out? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here are the bits of my code that might help out

```
var fav = $('#favorites');

// Open & close button
$('#favorites_a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    fav.toggle();
});

$('a.c',fav).live('click', function(e) {
    alert('hey');
});

$(document).click(function() {
    fav.hide();
});

fav.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

HTML (built after page load):

```
<div id="favorites">
    <div class="wrap">
        <ul><li><a href="/abc" class="p">A</a><a href="#" class="c">B</a></li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does the javascript one link look like? Did you try with e.preventDefault();

Comment: Would you post your html and JS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a problem with the `live()` click event handler. When you use `live` the event handler is actually attached to the document. So the event needs to bubble up to the document, but your click event handler on `fav` prevents bubbling up.

It works with [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) though:

```
fav.delegate('a.c', 'click', function(e) {
    alert('hey');
});
```

Here, the event handler is added to `fav`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KHYKW/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code for fav is preventing the 'B' link from working. Instead of .live(), try:

```
$('a.c').click(function() { ... });
```

instead.